# Strongloop UUID

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

heres a snippet of the model I've created. I would like the id property to be ALWAYS automatically generated via the uuid default function. However, when even added to hidden the id property could be decide by the user if they pass that into the post create method.

Other than using the method hooks OR operation hooks, to always overwrite the value is there another Loopback approach or flag (I have tried the foreId property as well) to ensure that the id is always a uuid even when the user provides a value? If not then for my case, "defaultFn": "uuid" completely pointless, if I'm always overwriting it.

```
{ 
  "name": "Account",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "strict": true,
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "id": true,
      "required": true,
      "type": "string",
      "defaultFn": "uuid"
    },
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Comment: Don't know why you got downvoted, because this is a perfectly valid question (and I discovered something thanks to it)

Comment: @Overdrivr me either since I couldn't see an answer anywhere :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, the id can be redefined by the user through the REST api and is not protected when using `idInjection: false` and defining a custom id property.

I'll open a ticket on github if it's not already done, in the meantime you can fix it easily using a `before save` [operation hook](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Operation-hooks.html#before-save)

In Account.js, using the [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) package

```
const uuidV4 = require('uuid/v4');
module.exports = function(Account) {
  Account.observe('before save', function(ctx, cb){
    if (ctx.instance) {
      ctx.instance.id = uuidV4();
    } else {
      ctx.data.id = uuidV4();
    }
    cb();
  });
};
```

Comment: Choosing this as the answer since this was the same approach I took. It just seems silly you can specify a defaultFn but a user can overwrite the value any time they please.

Comment: Well, there is the `forceId` property, but it does not seem to work at all. Ticket is opened [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3029#issuecomment-267143569).